# Iterating through an ArrayList in a HashMap

Tags: java

I have the following HashMap:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> mat = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

which looks like this:

```
1: [2, 3]
2: [1, 4, 5]
3: [1, 6, 7]
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get the size of the ArrayList in the i-th entry of my HashMap ?
2. How do I access the i-th element in my ArrayList on a given key?

Comment: `(ArrayList) mat.get(i).size()` will give you the size of the list.

Comment: Does the i-th entry in the map have key `i`? A 1-based index? --- Is the i-th element in the list 1-based or 0-based?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I get the size of the ArrayList in the i-th entry of my HashMap ?

I assume that you mean the entry whose key is `i`.  (Since the elements of a `HashMap` are not ordered, it is not meaningful to talk about the i-th entry of a `HashMap`.)

```
   ArrayList<Integer> tmp = mat.get(i);
   if (tmp != null) {
       System.out.println("The size is " + tmp.size());
   }
```

> How do I access the i-th element in my ArrayList on a given key?

I assume that you want normal (for Java) zero-based indexing of the array

```
   ArrayList<Integer> tmp = mat.get(key);
   if (tmp != null && i >= 0 && i < tmp.size()) {
       System.out.println("The element is " + tmp.get(i));
   }
```

Note that there are various *edge-cases* that need to be dealt with if you want to avoid exceptions.  (I have dealt with them ...)

Comment: `i << tmp.size()`? Was your `<` key a bit sticky there? --- Also, if OP considers i-th to be 1-3 for the map indexes (aka keys), perhaps OP also consider i-th to be 1-based for the list, not 0-based like Java does, so you need `get(i - 1)` and corresponding changes to range check.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get the size of the ArrayList in the i-th entry of my HashMap ?

---

if the **i** is not a `key` of your HashMap, I'm afraid that we cant get the `i-th entry` of HashMap directly.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap can contain null values, so you need to do the `null` check before using the `size()` and `get(i)` of the `arraylist`.

**1) How do I get the size of the ArrayList in the i-th entry of my HashMap ?**

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = mat.get(i);
if(list != null) {
   list.size(); //gives the size of the list
}
```

**2) How do I access the i-th element in my ArrayList on a given key?**

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = mat.get(i);
    if(list != null) {
       list.get(i);//gives the i-th element from list
   }
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)